# Find all matches in a varchar2()

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I've a column that is a `varchar2` that contains data like: `....[A1]...[A2]...`
I want to take out all data that is encapsulated by `[]` that starts with an alphabetic letter and can have either one or two number, i.e: `[B1]`, `[B23]`.

So I want something like: "WHERE column is like `'[__]' OR column is like '[___]'` but `_` isnt just any value but alphabetic or numeric.

And is it possible to store them in someway for later use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! [Here's a Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd65d/1) showing how to query the matches into a result set.

And here's the long explanation in case the query in the Fiddle doesn't make sense :)

I'm using a table named `RegEx_Test` with a column `MyVal`. Here's the table's contents:

```
MyVal
------------------------------
[A1][abc][B23][D123]a33[bx5]
[Z15][ax0][B0][F13]R3
[X215][A3A][J99]F33F33G24[43][R3]
[Z99][c1][F3][d33]3x24[Y3][f13]
[9a][D41][Q39][XX12]B27[T03][J12]
```

Your regexp throughout is this: `\[[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]{1,2}\]`. It's the same as in the other answer except with the POSIX `:alpha:` and `:digit:` indicators, which are safer in case of international charactersets.

First, you need to know the maximum number of matches on any line. Use `REGEXP_COUNT` for this:

```
SELECT MAX(REGEXP_COUNT(MyVal, '\[[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]{1,2}\]'))
  FROM Regex_Test

MAX(REGEXP_COUNT(My...
----------------------
                     6
```

Use that maximum count to get a "counter" table (that's the `SELECT ... FROM DUAL` below) and cross-join the counter table with a query that will pull your values using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`. `REGEXP_SUBSTR` has an "occurrence" parameter and that will use the `Counter`:

```
SELECT
  MyVal,
  Counter,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(MyVal, '\[[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]{1,2}\]', 1, Counter) Matched
FROM Regex_Test
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT LEVEL Counter
   FROM DUAL
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (
     SELECT MAX(REGEXP_COUNT(MyVal, '\[[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]{1,2}\]'))
     FROM Regex_Test)) Counters
```

Here's a sample run against my table (partial results):

```
MyVal                              Counter Matched
---------------------------------- ------- -------
[9a][D41][Q39][XX12]B27[T03][J12]        1 [D41]
[9a][D41][Q39][XX12]B27[T03][J12]        2 [Q39]
[9a][D41][Q39][XX12]B27[T03][J12]        3 [T03]
[9a][D41][Q39][XX12]B27[T03][J12]        4 [J12]
[9a][D41][Q39][XX12]B27[T03][J12]        5
[9a][D41][Q39][XX12]B27[T03][J12]        6
[A1][abc][B23][D123]a33[bx5]             1 [A1]
[A1][abc][B23][D123]a33[bx5]             2 [B23]
[A1][abc][B23][D123]a33[bx5]             3
... and so on - total is 30 rows
```

At this point you have a result set of individual matches, plus nulls where a row had less than the maximum matches. The matches still have their surrounding brackets. Surround the whole thing with an outer query that will filter out the nulls and remove the brackets, and you have your final list:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Matched, 2, LENGTH(Matched)-2) FROM (
  SELECT
    MyVal,
    Counter,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(MyVal, '\[[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]{1,2}\]', 1, Counter) Matched
  FROM Regex_Test
  CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT LEVEL Counter
     FROM DUAL
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (
       SELECT MAX(REGEXP_COUNT(MyVal, '\[[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]{1,2}\]'))
       FROM Regex_Test)) Counters
) WHERE Matched IS NOT NULL
```

This is the query that's on the Fiddle, and it can be used in another query.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`REGEXP_LIKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) to find values matching your regular expression:

```
[...] WHERE REGEXP(col_name, '\[[A-Z][0-9]{1,2}\]');
```

Comment: [...] WHERE REGEXP(col_name, '\[[A-Z][0-9]{1,2}\]'); gives the same result as REGEXP_LIKE (col_name, '\[[A-Z][0-9]{1,1}\]'. As I interpeted it the first regex operation looks for 2 numbers while the second one search for one number.

Comment: WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (col_name, '\[[A-E]{1}[0-9]{2}\]') solved it!

Comment: Now is it a way to store the [..] matches and use them in another query?