# Creating a view in a not relational database

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle, view

I had an issue and I hope that someone could help me out. In fact, I work on a poorly designed database and I have no control to change things in it. I have a table "Books", and each book can have one or more author. Unfortunately the database is not fully relational (please don't ask me why because I am asking the same question from the beginning). In the table "Books" there is a field called "Author_ID" and "Author_Name", so when a book was written by 2 or 3 authors their IDs and Their names will be concatenated in the same record separated by an star. Here is a demonstration:

```
ID_BOOK | ID_AUTHOR |       NAME AUTHOR       |  Adress        |  Country        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001     |01         | AuthorU                 | AdrU           | CtryU           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
002     |02*03*04   | AuthorX*AuthorY*AuthorZ | AdrX*NULL*AdrZ | NULL*NULL*CtryZ |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to create a view against this table that would give me this result:

```
ID_BOOK | ID_AUTHOR |       NAME AUTHOR       | Adress         | Country         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001     |01         | AuthorU                 | AdrU           | CtryU           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
002     |02         | AuthorX                 | AdrX           | NULL            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
002     |03         | AuthorY                 | NULL           | NULL            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
002     |04         | AuthorZ                 | AdrZ           | CtryZ           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I will continue trying to do it and I hope that someone could help me with at least some hints. Many thanks guys.

After I applied the solution given by you guys I got this problem. I am trying to solve it and hopefully you can help me. In fact, when the sql query run, the CLOB fields are disorganized when some of them contain NULL value. The reslut should be like above, but i got the result below:

```
ID_BOOK | ID_AUTHOR |       NAME AUTHOR       | Adress         | Country         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001     |01         | AuthorU                 | AdrU           | CtryU           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
002     |02         | AuthorX                 | AdrX           | CtryZ           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
002     |03         | AuthorY                 | AdrZ           | NULL            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
002     |04         | AuthorZ                 | NULL           | NULL            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why does it put the NULL values in the end? Thank you.

Comment: good question bad title

Comment: Hey Praveen, It's my first question here. I tried many titles but every time it says that the title is not good, so i started looking for a title that can be approved. Your remark is correct. Please if you have any hint let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple weeks ago I answered a similar question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434396/find-all-matches-in-a-varchar2/15437392#15437392). That answer has an explanation (I hope) of the general approach so I'll skip the explanation here. This query will do the trick; it uses `REGEXP_REPLACE` and leverages its "occurrence" parameter to pick the individual author ID's and names:

```
SELECT
 ID_Book,
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(ID_Author, '[^*]+', 1, Counter) AS AuthID,
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name_Author, '[^*]+', 1, Counter) AS AuthName
FROM Books
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT LEVEL Counter
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (      
      SELECT MAX(REGEXP_COUNT(ID_Author, '[^*]+'))
      FROM Books))
WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name_Author, '[^*]+', 1, Counter) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

There's a Fiddle with your data plus another row [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0f19/2).

---

**Addendum**: OP has Oracle 9, not 11, so regular expressions won't work. Following are instructions for doing the same task without regexes...

Without `REGEXP_COUNT`, the best way count authors is to count the asterisks and add one. To count asterisks, take the length of the string, then subtract its length when all the asterisks are sucked out of it: `LENGTH(ID_Author) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ID_Author, '*'))`.

Without `REGEX_SUBSTR`, you need to use `INSTR` to find the position of the asterisks, and then `SUBSTR` to pull out the author IDs and names. This gets a little complicated - consider these Author columns from your original post:

```
Author U
Author X*Author Y*Author Z
```

- `AuthorX` lies between the beginning the string and the first asterisk.
- `AuthorY` is surrounded by asterisks
- `AuthorZ` lies between the last asterisk and the end of the string.
- `AuthorU` is all alone and not surrounded by anything.

Because of this, the opening piece (`WITH AuthorInfo AS...` below) adds an asterisk to the beginning and the end so every author name (and ID) is surrounded by asterisks. It also grabs the author count for each row. For the sample data in your original post, the opening piece will yield this:

```
ID_Book  AuthCount  ID_Author   Name_Author
-------  ---------  ----------  -------------------------
001              1  *01*        *AuthorU*
002              3  *02*03*04*  *AuthorX*AuthorY*AuthorZ*
```

Then comes the join with the "Counter" table and the `SUBSTR` machinations to pull out the individual names and IDs. The final query looks like this:

```
WITH AuthorInfo AS (
  SELECT
    ID_Book,
    LENGTH(ID_Author) -
        LENGTH(REPLACE(ID_Author, '*')) + 1 AS AuthCount,
    '*' || ID_Author || '*' AS ID_Author,
    '*' || Name_Author || '*' AS Name_Author
  FROM Books
)
SELECT
  ID_Book,
  SUBSTR(ID_Author,
    INSTR(ID_Author, '*', 1, Counter) + 1,
    INSTR(ID_Author, '*', 1, Counter+1) - INSTR(ID_Author, '*', 1, Counter) - 1) AS AuthID,
  SUBSTR(Name_Author,
    INSTR(Name_Author, '*', 1, Counter) + 1,
    INSTR(Name_Author, '*', 1, Counter+1) - INSTR(Name_Author, '*', 1, Counter) - 1) AS AuthName
FROM AuthorInfo
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT LEVEL Counter
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX(AuthCount) FROM AuthorInfo))
WHERE AuthCount >= Counter
ORDER BY ID_Book, Counter
```

The Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0f19/14)

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies, i'll try them. Just I want to add a remark, the Author_ID and Author_Name are CLOB data and the deliminator is not exactly a start but is a wordrap, so i'll try to adapt your requests and convert this CLOB data to Varchar to be able to play with them.

Comment: @Walloud - Oracle has ways to handle multi-line regular expressions but I'm afraid I don't know them that well so I can't be of much help from here on. If you run into questions with a multi-line regular expression I'd recommend posting a new question and tagging it as "regular expression" in addition to Oracle - that way your question will be seen by a lot of RegEx experts. Good luck, and great question!

Comment: Hey Grace, I work with Oracle 9 so this code doesn't work for me because Oracle 9 doesn't understand the regular expressions, I'm trying to adapt it but still not getting correct result. Could you please give me some hints? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Walloud - I've added the 9i query (with some explanation) to the answer above. At least I *think* it's 9i-compliant - let me know if you run into any problems.

Comment: Hey Ed ! I've really no word to describe how much I want to thank you. You're really gooooooood man! Yesterday I fixed my issue but I forgot to write to you. I'll take your solution and understand it so I can enhance my skills and may be once i'll help people like you're doing. Thank you again !! Cheers :)))

Comment: You're welcome @Walloud! Doing the query in 9i was educational for me (and actually kind of fun) because it forced me to think more about setup and design, whereas in 11 it was just running with the regex stuff. I'm really pleased it worked out for you - I've had to deal with plenty of bad databases so I feel your pain :)

Comment: HI Ed Gibbs, I updated my post, could you please help me out? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Walloud - I'll try, but I don't understand where ClobField1, ClobField2 and ClobField3 are coming from. Can you explain? And I'll need to see your query; my answer didn't cover these columns so I need to see how you've worked them into the query. I don't have a lot of time today so if I can't get back to you today it may be as late as Sunday before I have anything, but I'll try my best.

Comment: Hi Ed Gibbs, thank you for your quick reply. I updated the 3 tables in my post , I hope that can help you to understand my issue. I'm sorry I can't put the sql query because i am not allowed to do it for professional reasons, but i am using your solution. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Walloud, when you say the Address column is like this: `AdrX*NULL*AdrZ`, do you mean it literally has the word "NULL" between the asterisks? Or do you mean its value is actually `AdrX**AdrZ`?

Comment: Hey Ed. In fact the Deliminator is Ch(13) but here in my example I put "*". I think there is nothing in between.

Comment: Hi Walloud, the `DUMP` function will help show the "invisible" characters. Please try this query and paste the results in the comment: `SELECT DUMP(Adress) FROM Books WHERE ID_BOOK = '002'`.

Comment: Hey Ed, first DUMP(Adress) didn't work so I wrote DUMP(TO_CHAR(Adress)). It gave me a result like that Typ=1 Len=275:114,101.....many numbers. I can't understand this output !

Comment: In the DUMP output, do you see any 13's very close to each other? Something like `116,103,114,13,13,104` or `116,103,114,13,0,13,104` or `116,103,114,13,32,13,104`? If so, can you tell me what, if any, values are between the 13's?

Comment: I can't see any 13 !! Here is the output : 114,101,97,99,104,32,100,56,48,44,32,115,101,110,100,32,101,101,32,112,107,103,10,114,101,97,99,104,32,100,57,48,44,32,114,101,113,117,101,115,116,32,112,115,115,32,102,114,111,109,32,109,103,114,10,114,101,97,99,104,32,100,49,48,54,10,108,116,100,32,99,108,97,105,109,32,115,116,97,116,117,115,10,108,116,100,32,99,108,97,105,109,32,115,116,97,116,117,115,10,114,116,119,44,32,115,101,110,100,32,110,111,116,105,102,99,97,116,105,111,110,32,101,109,97,105,108,10,114,116,119,44,32,115,101,110,100,32,110,111,116,105,102,99,97,116,105,111,110,32,101,109

Comment: Hi Walloud - your delimiter is `CHR(10)`, not `CHR(13)`. The DUMP shows the ASCII values, and I see some 10's there. Example: `117,115,10,108,116,100,32,99,108,97,105,109`. That's `us{line-feed}ltd claim`. The problem is that you've got *five* of these and I only expected to find *two*. Does each address have two lines?

Comment: First Part of the comment : Hi Ed, something is weird. The first time I posted this post I wanted to duplicate a record as much as there is sub-records in the CLOB fields.

Comment: Second Part of the comment: When I split on CHR(13) it gives me the table 2 which I expect (but column Adress and Country disorganized), but when I split on CHR(10) it gives me only one record ! How come my delimiter is CHR(10) but it gives me one occurance? :( As I told you Ed, I don't publish my real work so I am using an example here, the adress column correspond to another column in the real world, it can has more than 2 lines, when I count the CHR(10) and add 1 I have the correct number of the lines, so Why only one line is shown when I split on it? thank you again man!

Comment: Hi Walloud, there's a SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e19e1/1) that I think may be close. Note that I created the address values using CHR(10) delimiters, and note that it handles several types of "records": single author, three authors but #2 is blank, three authors but #3 is blank, etc. The only change in the query on the right is the part that pulls out the two address lines. I won't be available much tomorrow but I should be around Sunday if you have any followup questions.

Comment: Thanks again Ed, I am struggling, The counter is incremented correctly and the query generate the right number of records but all columns are returned null ! When I change the value of the counter manually in the INSTR, it works fine ! Weird ! Why it does return null when the counter is incremented automatically but when I put hardcoded number it gives me the right value in the CLOB field? Sorry man !

Comment: Hi Walloud, without seeing the query I can't really tell. Does the Fiddle in my comment from May 4 look more or less like your tables? Please take a look, and if you see any differences could you make a new Fiddle and post the link back in a comment?

Comment: Hi Ed! You are right that you need a Fiddle to understand but unfortunately I can't paste my code in the website. Believe me it's the same query with same type of fields but with the cross join I got the right number of records (that's mean that the counter is correct) but the select return columns with null value. When I delete the cross join and i hardcode the counter in the INSTR it picks the right record with the value that correspond to the hardcoded counter. Thank you for all that you've done for me, now I have the code and I must find a solution. Thanks again dude !

Comment: No problem Walloud :) I understand that you can't post the real data, but if you hit a wall then see if you can post a sanitized version; I may be able to work from that. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks dude :) Good luck for you too !

Answer (score 2):

in 11g you can use a factored recursive sub query for this:

```
with data (id_book, id_author, name, item_author, item_name, i)
 as (select id_book, id_author, name,
            regexp_substr(id_author, '[^\*]+', 1, 1) item_author, 
            regexp_substr(name, '[^\*]+', 1, 1) item_name,
            2 i 
       from books
     union all
     select id_book, id_author, name,
            regexp_substr(id_author, '[^\*]+', 1, i) item_author, 
            regexp_substr(name, '[^\*]+', 1, i) item_name, 
            i+1
       from data
      where regexp_substr(id_author, '[^\*]+', 1, i) is not null)
select id_book, item_author, item_name
  from data;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5fcac/1)

Comment: thank you Dazza. Just another question please, the columns Author_ID and Author_Name are CLOB data and the deliminator is a wordrap (not a star), do you think the best solution is to convert CLOB to VARCHAR then apply ur request? Otherwise the regexp_substr won't work.

Comment: @walloud is the data in the columns ever over 4k then?

Comment: I really don't know how to know it Dazzal, i'm not familiar with CLOB :S

Comment: @walloud you can check with select max(length(id_author)) from books; if it's not over 4k the Applying a to_char around the field will get round the clob problem eg regexp_substr(to_char(id_author)...

Comment: Hey Dazzal, thanks agaim, I did it and it gave 57 caracters, to know how many k, what do i have to do please?

Comment: @Walloud 57 is very tiny. you didn't need a clob to store it, so if using regexp_substr on its own is giving issues just use the to_char as i gave before

Comment: Hey Dazzal, I'm not the guy that create the DB... Plus, the DB is Oracle 9 so the solution that guys gave me here doesn't work because regular expressions are not handled with Oracle 9 so I'm trying to adapt the solution, hopefully i finish it today, i've a lot of work !

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `authors` table, you can do:

```
select b.id_book, a.id_author, a.NameAuthor
from books b left outer join
     authors a
     on '*'||NameAuthor||'*' like '%*||a.author||'*%'
```

Comment: Thank you for responding Gordon. Unfortunately I don't have an Author table. And the perfect solution for me is a view against the table Books. thanks again !

Comment: @Walloud . . . That's a shame.  The solution using `connect` is the way to go then.

Comment: What's the shame Gordon? Please explain when you use such words.

Comment: @Walloud . . . It is a shame that you have a database with books, but don't have a table for their authors.  That's all.  You say in the question that the database is not well designed and you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In addition:

```
SELECT distinct id_book,
     , trim(regexp_substr(id_author, '[^*]+', 1, LEVEL)) id_author
     , trim(regexp_substr(author_name, '[^*]+', 1, LEVEL)) author_name
 FROM yourtable
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(id_author, '[^*]+')
ORDER BY id_book, id_author
/

ID_BOOK    ID_AUTHOR    AUTHOR_NAME
------------------------------------
001        01           AuthorU
002        02           AuthorX
002        03           AuthorY
002        04           AuthorZ
003        123          Jane Austen
003        456          David Foster Wallace
003        789          Richard Wright
```

No REGEXP:

```
SELECT str, SUBSTR(str, substr_start_pos, substr_end_pos) final_str
  FROM
 (
  SELECT str, substr_start_pos
       , (CASE WHEN substr_end_pos <= 0 THEN (Instr(str, '*', 1)-1) 
            ELSE substr_end_pos END) substr_end_pos
    FROM
   (
   SELECT distinct '02*03*04' AS str
       , (Instr('02*03*04', '*', LEVEL)+1) substr_start_pos
       , (Instr('02*03*04', '*', LEVEL)-1) substr_end_pos           
    FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length('02*03*04')
   )
  ORDER BY substr_start_pos
  )
 /

STR         FINAL_STR
---------------------
02*03*04    02
02*03*04    03
02*03*04    04
```

Comment: Hey Art, I work with Oracle 9 so this code doesn't work for me because Oracle 9 doesn't understand the regular expressions, I'm trying to adapt it but still not getting correct result. Could you please give me some hints? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Walloud-Sorry, I saw others using regexp and assume your can too. Please see update.

Comment: Small correction: WHEN substr_end_pos <= 0 THEN - substr_end_pos less or equal 0.